# Different proofs of $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)^n =e$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, limits, exponential-function

I recently was teaching my friend about the number $e$. I introduced him the number by using the compound interest thing . Then I wrote down the general result -$$\lim_{x\to  \infty}\left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)^n =e$$ The he told me that yes it works for  $n=10,100,200,1000$. Beyond that his computer couldn't check . So he asked me for a formal mathematical proof of it . I thought of one but then that proof had natural logarithms - meaning they involved the number $e$ .I want to know the different ways through which this results can be proved , but without any use of $e$.

Comment: How can you prove the result "without any use of $e$" if the answer is itself $e$?

Comment: How do you define $e$? Afaik, it's normally _defined_ as the limit you want to prove.

Comment: Does he have a VIC 20? Google can calculate the value (approximately of course) for $n=100000000$ (and much higher values, I'm sure).

Comment: You can introduce it by series to him, consequently he may calculate it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go [limit proof of e](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma122/elimit.pdf).

Comment: Good paper ! Thanks.